# Проблемы с наследованием в C#

Tags: c#, ооп, классы, наследование

я только изучаю C#, не нашёл ответ на первой странице Google поэтому создаю вопрос.

Насколько я понял, *protected* поля данных родительских классов **должны наследоваться** их производными.
Я начал пытаться реализовать это на практике:

```
class Program
{
    class Human
    {
        string Name; //В видео из интернета которое я смотрел, всё работало
    }

    class Student: Human
    {

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student a = new Student();
        a.Name = "Nikolay";
    }
}
```

**Результат:** Ошибка   CS0122  'Program.Human.Name" недоступен из-за его уровня защиты.

Насколько я понял, если не указано иное, поле класса создаётся с модификатором **private** (что и происходит в листинге). Однако, подстановка **protected** не решает моей проблемы, и в видео из интернета, с которого я копировал код, всё работало без спецификации поля данных.

Я буду очень благодарен, если бы вы указать на мою ошибку. Я хотел бы заставить программу наследовать поля данных от родительского класса.

Comment: Ключевое слово protected просто позволяет видеть внутри производного класса (Student) поля (и другое) базового класса (Human).

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к полю не из наследника, а из другого третьего класса, такому классу можно обращаться только к public-членам

Answer (score 2):

Вы немного путаете уровни доступа к полям класса.
protected это значит доступно внутри потомка, а не так как у вас. Вы пытаетесь получить с наружи в программе доступ как public свойство.
Поле protected Name в вашем случае доступно внутри Student, а не в Program

Comment: Да нет не сказать, что сложное. Просто появились уровни доступа которые тяжело представить в контексте инкапсуляции

Comment: Начинать нужно с простого и не бежать вперед если изучаешь. Не понятно остановись и разберись иначе в переди будет более не понятно

Comment: Я когда ещё на PascalABC.NET писал как-то сам всё понял :D Там всё такое же, только без св-в, но с событиями, и с C++'овскими `public:`, но без двоеточия :)

Comment: Хотелось бы сказать новичкам, как я этому обучился и какие проблемы возникали... Да только я почти ничего не помню... Не называйте переменные `arr1` и `arr2`, и всё будет хорошо

Answer (score -1):

```
class Human {
    private string PrivateName = "Private Name";
    protected string ProtectedName = "Protected Name";
    public string PublicName = "Public Name";

    public void PrintPrivateName () {
        print(PrivateName);
    }
}

class Student: Human {
    
    public void PrintProtectedName () {
        print(ProtectedName);
    }
}

static void Main (string[] args) {
    Student NewStudent = new Student();
    NewStudent.PrintPrivateName();
    NewStudent.PrintProtectedName();
    print(NewStudent.PublicName);
}
```

Comment: Может код и по делу, но надо же и комментировать

Comment: Ни разу не видел на C# реальные исходники в таком стиле. Это из VB.NET или откуда такое именование? Про скобки в стиле Java промолчу (знаю, что у них есть название, но мне как-то всё равно и лень искать).

Comment: Локальные переменные испокон веков именовались в C# с маленькой буквы (NewStudent  -> newStudent), а методы с большой. Поля private или protected с маленькой буквы или с символа подчёркивания. Public поля, может быть, в качестве примера и сойдут, но это плохой тон делать в классе открытые поля, которые не readonly. Уверен, кто-то дизлайк поставил по одной из этих причин (я не ставил).

Comment: Про `{ }` я такой не один, в `С#` нас таких ~17% и это не приступление, я начинал с других языков. Я программист, я так вижу =D. С именованием в реальном коде преступление, но это не реальный код (Более реальный https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160670/Как-оптимизировать-разворот-объекта-в-полете/1160687#1160687). В теге `unity3d` на стеке на это не обращают внимания в принцее, правда он тут вобщемто не причем и RiotBr3aker его убрал.